# Python: Print the longest word in a sentence that contains specific letters

Tags: python

If there is no word contains "a" or "A" in a sentence, print -1.

Here is my code, I can print the words if they contain "a" or "A", but if not I can't manage to print -1 out.

Where should I change?

```
def newsentence ():
    letters = set('aA')
    new_ls = [word for word in sentence if letters & set(word)]
    return new_ls

def findlongest ():
    if 'a' or 'A' in sentence: 
        longest = max(newsentence(), key=len)
    else:
        longest== -1
    return(longest)
    
sentence = list(input().split())
print(findlongest())
```

Comment: You're comparing in `else` block i.e. `longest== -1`. Instead of this assign -1 to longest i.e.   `longest = -1`

Comment: Please update your question with some sample inputs and your actual outputs.

Comment: The reason the `-1` statement is not executing is because the `if` statement *always* evaluates to `True`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71936409/6340496).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `newsentence` will return an empty array if there is no `a` or `A`. Please change the code to below. It should work. As @Tomer said, you also need to change == to = as well

```
def newsentence ():
    letters = set('aA')
    new_ls = [word for word in sentence if letters & set(word)]
    return new_ls

def findlongest ():
    if newsentence():
        longest = max(newsentence(), key=len)
    else:
        longest = -1
    return(longest)

sentence = list(input().split())
print(findlongest())
```

Comment: The first `if` in `findlongest()` is completely redundant.

Comment: Thanks @quamrana ... you are right, removed the first IF

Comment: Yes, the first `if` was also redundant because the `newsentence()` function does the same thing. (btw you shouldn't be in the habit of calling a function twice when calling it once and saving the return value would work)

Answer (score 4):

Change `longest== -1` to `longest = -1`, this should solve the problem.

Another problem will be the If statement which is not written properly. change to the following:

```py
def findlongest (sentence):
    if any(['a' in word for word in sentence]) or any(['A' in word for word in sentence]):
        longest = max(newsentence(), key=len)
    else:
        longest = -1
    return(longest)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved very simply, as shown below:

```
max((x for x in sentence.split() if 'a' in x.lower()), key=len)
```

The sentence is split into words, where each word is tested for the lowercase `'a'`, as *all* words in the sentence are lower cased. Then the longest word based on length is returned.

---

#### As a function:

```
def findlongest(sentence: str):
    try:
        return max((x for x in sentence.split() if 'a' in x.lower()), key=len)
    except ValueError:
        return -1
```

Examples:

```
>>> findlongest('A longer word and a longA word.')
'longA'

>>> findlongest('A sentence with only one outcome.')
'A'

>>> findlongest('No words to return.')
-1
```

---

#### Explanation why the original code does not work as expected

The statement `if 'a' or 'A' in sentence` will **always** evaluate to `True`, via ['truthiness'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) logic. Therefore, it's not functioning as you think it is. The statement is actually evaluating as:

```
if ('a') or ('A' in sentence)
```

As a test, try `'a' or 2 in 'bob'` and you'll see.

Comment: Your `"in progress"` seems to be taking a long time. I find I get downvotes if I try this.

Comment: @quamrana -  Oops!  Alll done.  Thanks mate.

Comment: Ok, I see what you did. (Personally I don't approve of using exceptions as flow control, but I think I'm in a minority or maybe its just python)

Comment: @quamrana - *Generally*, I absolutely agree. I used them here to keep the logic as simple and transparent as possible.  'Time and place ...'